# Specify conditional number format when thousands and decimal separator are the same

Tags: excel, vba, localization

My macro is run on a virtual machine, that for some reason is using "," both as thousands and decimal separator. I want to avoid any dependency to the regional settings on that machine.

The workbook created by the macro has a checkbox for displaying amounts in thousands. I have implemented that as a conditional formatting that is applied when the checkbox is set ("checked"). The FormatCondition.NumberFormat property seems to require a local format string. I don't know if it is possible to create that string when the thousands and decimal separators are the same.

I have considered not using formatting, but to actually divide and round the values when the checkbox is ticked, but as I calculate the sum of these values, it would generate rounding errors downstream.

As an example, this code;

```
Sub TestFormatting()
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim baseFormats
    Dim condFormat As String
    Dim aNumber As Long
    Dim bIndex As Integer
    Dim cIndex As Integer
    
    baseFormats = Array("General", "###,###,##0")
    condFormat = "0" + Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)
    aNumber = 123456789
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "NumberFormat"
        .Cells(2, 1) = "Conditional NumberFormat"
        .Cells(3, 1) = "=TRUE"
        .Cells(4, 1) = "=FALSE"
        For bIndex = 0 To UBound(baseFormats)
            .Cells(1, 2 + bIndex) = baseFormats(bIndex)
            .Cells(2, 2 + bIndex) = condFormat
            .Cells(3, 2 + bIndex) = aNumber
            .Cells(4, 2 + bIndex) = aNumber
            Set aRange = .Range(.Cells(3, 2 + bIndex), .Cells(4, 2 + bIndex))
            aRange.NumberFormat = baseFormats(bIndex)
            Call aRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=$A3")
            aRange.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = condFormat
        Next bIndex
        With .UsedRange.columns
            .ColumnWidth = 30
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

When run with the described regional settings (both separators are ","), generates the following output:
[image]

I want it to generate the same output as when I change to using a period (".") as decimal separator:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how it works, but this update to the code seems to do the trick:

```
Sub TestFormatting()
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim baseFormats
    Dim condFormat As String
    Dim aNumber As Long
    Dim bIndex As Integer
    Dim cIndex As Integer
    Dim xstSep As String
    
    baseFormats = Array("General", "###,###,##0")
    aNumber = 123456789
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "NumberFormat"
        .Cells(2, 1) = "Conditional NumberFormat"
        .Cells(3, 1) = "=TRUE"
        .Cells(4, 1) = "=FALSE"
        For bIndex = 0 To UBound(baseFormats)
            .Cells(1, 2 + bIndex) = baseFormats(bIndex)
            .Cells(3, 2 + bIndex) = aNumber
            .Cells(4, 2 + bIndex) = aNumber
            Set aRange = .Range(.Cells(3, 2 + bIndex), .Cells(4, 2 + bIndex))
            aRange.NumberFormat = baseFormats(bIndex)
            Call aRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=$A3")
            
            ' >>> Temporarily change decimal separator and evaluate the conditional format string
            xstSep = Application.DecimalSeparator
            Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
            Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
            condFormat = "0" + Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)  ' Moved here from above
            .Cells(2, 2 + bIndex) = condFormat                                  ' Moved here from above
            aRange.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = condFormat
            Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
            Application.DecimalSeparator = xstSep
            ' <<<
            
        Next bIndex
        With .UsedRange.columns
            .ColumnWidth = 30
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

What it does is to temporarily set the decimal separator to period (.) during the application of the number format.